# Issues with Maven graniteds-tide-spring-jpa-hibernate archetype and Flex 4.5

Tags: apache-flex, spring, maven, graniteds

I'm trying to use the Maven archetype for Spring-GraniteDS-Tide-Hibernate-jpa. I can get the project to generate correctly, however, I need to use Flex Builder 4.5. If I change the settings in the main pom.xml, to use GraniteDS 2.2.1GA, Flex SDK 4.5.0.20967 and Flexmojos 3.9, I am able to do a clean mvn install without errors. I am able to deploy as well. However,when I run the application I get a "blank" page. The app is there, but just blank, if I right click on the app, I get the Flash player context menu.

I found a solution [here](http://groups.google.com/group/flex-mojos/browse_thread/thread/143f69219fcddc16#) but I am new to Maven and I have no idea where I should put this code. Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Thanks,
John

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `<configureation>` to the org.sonatype.flexmojos:flexmojos-maven-plugin plugin. There you can put all the configuration stuff.

Did you see the last post by:

> On 4 juil, 17:14, "John B."   wrote: